# CircuiTikZ: How to specify a components tolerance

Tags: latex

I have a schematic where I use a resistor of 50 ohms. I want to specify that this resistor needs to have a tolerance which is lower than 1%. How do I need to specify it? Below is my LaTeX code.
Now the tolerance is on the same line as my resistor. I want it to be placed below the resistor value.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw(0,0) node[vcc] (Vcc){5V} to[R, l_=$R_{sense}$, a^=$\SI{50}{\ohm} < \SI{1}{\percent}$] ++(0,-2) node[ground] (gnd) {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: please make a [mre], a small test document which we can compile to reproduce the probem

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw(0,0) node[vcc] (Vcc){5V} to[R, l_=$R_{\text{sense}}$, a^=\parbox{1cm}{\centering$\SI{50}{\ohm}$\linebreak$< \SI{1}{\percent}$}] ++(0,-2) node[ground] (gnd) {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrelated: please don't use math mode for multiletter words like `sense`, this messes up the kerning.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. You said that I shouldn't use math mode for multi letter words. I don't exactly get why, but besides that. What is the correct way to display the word sense? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @erwindenboer If you look closely at the output from your question you can see that e.g. the space between `n` and `s` in the word "sense" is too large. This happens because math basically assumes that each letter is an independence variable and does not correct the space to get a homogenous text flow. As shown in my answer, you can use `\text{sense}` instead.